# Structuring my Play framework app to be testable

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

I've been spinning up some knowledge on the play framework with slick, for a data driven app. I've followed the activator tutorial '[getting start on the right foot with slick](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/slick-starting-on-the-right-foot)'.

This led me to the design pattern which inherits a DB trait. Useful, because the controllers can now be easily tested by spinning up a little in memory DB. Lets say I have two controllers;

```
trait PerilQueryTrait extends Controller {  this: DBComponent => import driver.api._

trait RegionTrait extends Controller { this: DBComponent => import driver.api._

trait DBComponent {

  val driver: JdbcProfile

  import driver.api._

  val db: Database
}
```

The 'prod' app instantiates versions of the controller with a persistent DB. The test app has an H2 DB. Each controller then has a 'validate' method, which checks that an argument provided is valid against the data in the DB. Prod

```
class PerilQuery extends PerilQueryTrait with AConcreteDBComponent
class RegionQuery extends RegionTrait with AConcreteDBComponent
```

and test

```
class PerilQuery extends PerilQueryTrait with AnH2DBComponent
class RegionQuery extends RegionTrait with AnH2DBComponent
```

I want a third controller which composes the two validation methods...

**What's the recommended strategy for being able to compose the controller methods, in such a way that it remains testable?** 
My initial thought was simply instantiate the two controllers in a third, and call the methods separately. They are stateless, so that would work, but I don't think it's easily testable because then the code I think needs to know at compile time whether it's prod or test.

Have a third trait with those two traits ?

```
trait CombinedTrait with PerilQueryTrait with RegionTrait { this: DBComponent => import driver.api._
```

Dependency Injection ?

A fourth strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is here... oops.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.4/ScalaActionsComposition

Should have read more carefully.